# measure length of edittext string dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, charactercount

How can i measure length of string entered in the edittext while typing.Because i want to show a warning when the entered text length cross 100 character.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` to do that in Android.

Something like this

```
 EditText test = new EditText(this);
        test.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                   //write your code here
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```